# Finding basis of a submodule in $\mathbb{Z}^2$?

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory, vector-spaces, modules, free-modules

I will be direct. This is an assignment question and I am not looking for someone to solve it for me. I want to do it myself and I am only looking for some direction and resources I can use.

1. Find the basis of $$R_f=\mathbb{Z}+f\mathbb{Z}^2 \subset \mathbb{Z}^2, f\in \mathbb{Z}$$ and $\mathbb{Z}$ is the subring $(1,1)\mathbb{Z}$ in $\mathbb{Z}^2$.

What I know : $$R_f=(1,1)\mathbb{Z}+f((1,0)\mathbb{Z}+(0,1)\mathbb{Z})$$ and that $(1,1)(f,0)(0,f)$ may not be the basis over $\mathbb{Z}^2$. I went about doing the standard elimination which one does for finding basis in $\mathbb{R}^n$ but that is not helping me. Also, searching a bit tells me that it the procedure is not the same over $\mathbb{Z}^n$ as in $\mathbb{R^n}$ so how do I do it? Any online resources I can use or please somebody help me how it is done?

2. Also, how does one find a basis in any ring or factor ring like $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2)$?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you are considering $R_f$ as a module over $\mathbb Z$ (there are no vector spaces here, as we don't have any fields hanging around).

So $$ R_f=\{(z,z)+(nf,mf):\ z,n,m\in\mathbb Z\}=\{z(1,1)+n(f,0)+m(0,f):\ z,n,m\in\mathbb Z\}
$$

The elements $(1,1),(f,0),(0,f)$ are not linearly independent:  $$-f(1,1)+(f,0)+(0,f)=(0,0).$$ We cannot have $(1,1)$ as a linear combination of $(f,0)$ and $0,f)$ (if $f\ne1$). But 
$$
(0,f)=f(1,1)-(f,0),
$$
for instace. So $(1,1),(f,0)$ is a basis for $R_f$, and so is $(1,1),(0,f)$.

---

For something like $\mathbb Z[x]/(x^2)$, you have that $p+(x^2)=q+(x)^2$ if and only if $p-q\in (x^2)$. So, if $p=a+bx+r(x)$, $q=c+dx+s(x)$ with $r(x),s(x)\in(x^2)$, then $p-q\in(x^2)$ means that $a=c$, $b=d$. So a basis for $\mathbb Z[x]/(x^2)$ (over $\mathbb Z$) is given by 
$$
1+(x^2),\ x+(x^2).
$$

Comment: Thank you so much for the second question. I get the idea now(which I find it so difficult to get in this course). For #1) (1,1)(f,0)(0,f) is the spanning set which I have but my question is how to get the basis out of these? I am supposed to calculate the determinant and considering these three as the basis gives me det. 0 which I know is wrong. Also, while we are at it, the Tr(a,b)=ab right or am I totally wrong in that? I am trying to remember everything but everything looks so complex to understand.

Comment: Now I read that in the question you wrote that you wanted a basis over $\mathbb Z^2$; that makes no sense, as far as I can tell, because $R_f$ is not closed when you multiply by elements of $\mathbb Z^2$. It is obvious that $(1,1),(0,f),(f,0)$ are linearly independent; I'll edit it into the answer. I have no idea what determinant you are talking about, so I cannot help you with that. And, finally, I have no idea what you mean by $\text{Tr}(a,b)$.

Comment: Forget about the "linearly independent" part. I'm editing the answer.

Comment: OK so I will explain myself. If $e_1$ and $e_2$ are the basis  of a module M then its determinant is the determinant of the matrix formed by Tr($e_{i}e_j$) where Tr is the trace and i=1 and j=2

Comment: I don't really follow. In general, the elements of a module cannot be multiplied; and even when they can be multiplied, they are not numbers, in general, so I still don't know what you mean by the trace.

Comment: Alright thanks a lot nonetheless. It really helps. Just a last quick question, how(to know)/ why did you consider the the condition $p-q \in\ x^2$ for Q2? I want to know how to do these problems, what should I be looking for?

Comment: When you quotient by an ideal $J$, the element of the quotient are $p+J$, and $J$ is the zero of the quotient. So $p-q\in J$ is the same as saying that $(p+J)-(q+J)$ is zero in the quotient, i.e. that $p+J=q+J$.